# Which jest configuration issues might cause tests to fail only in --coverage mode?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, react-testing-library

After upgrading jest, upgrading from React 16 to 17 and switching to `react-testing-library` from `enzyme`, all my front-end tests pass when I run them normally, but 6 (out of more than 50) suites fail only when I run the tests with `--coverage` enabled. In some cases I'm able to tweak tests or the app code itself to get them to pass in coverage mode, usually it means changing the syntax I'm using for destructuring objects or declaring imports, which makes me think it's a babel configuration issue. But some of them I can't get to pass and don't want to spend the time rewriting dozens of tests that work fine when I run them normally and only fail in coverage mode; I'd rather just figure out the configuration/transformation issue and change it for the whole project than pick apart and rewrite all my tests.

Weeks of research has led me to believe that this has something to do with either the test environment configuration, babel configuration, or coverage provider, all of which may be different when running in `--coverage` mode. For example, some people who had similar issues were able to resolve them by switching from `istanbul` to `v8` as the coverage provider, changing the `testEnvironment`, or upgrading packages like `babel@core`, `jest-cli`, or `jest-babel`. But I can't figure out how to narrow down the problem and I have tried all of these suggestions without success -- still getting all tests passing in normal testing mode, and 6 suites failing in `--coverage` mode.

I have tried:

- upgrading `jest-cli`, adding `babel-plugin-istanbul@next` as
  suggested here: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2007
- changing `coverageProvider` to `v8`, changing `testEnvironment` to
  `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` as suggested here:
  https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/622
- deleting lockfile and node_modules; reinstalling all packages
- upgrading `jest`, `@babel-core`, `babel-jest`

Anybody have any ideas how to narrow down which configuration options might be different between normal testing mode and coverage mode? I'm using `craco` to modify configuration without ejecting CRA (this is the only way I was able to change the coverage provider). So I could theoretically try modifying other configuration keys but I don't know what else might be worth trying.